# Having an issues when downloading app from xcode to my iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, ios-simulator

I'm getting errors when I download my app onto my iphone. The app downloads and works correctly on my iphone, but i'm missing 2 .png files within the app that are causing error messages. Error message's example:

Whilereading/Users/jimi9991/Documents/DeveloperProjects/TennisMatch4/LightWoodBackground.png pngcrush caught libpng error:

Could not find file: /Users/jimi9991/Documents/DeveloperProjects/TennisMatch4/build/Debug-iphoneos/TennisMatch4.app/LightWoodBackground.png

Comment: Check out for the named png's those will be in some other folder(not in your resources).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **"Whilereading/Users/jimi9991/Documents/DeveloperProjects/TennisMatch4/LightWoodBackground.png pngcrush caught libpng error:"**

Please clean your `build` and also `remove build folder`. Open those png files in `Preview` application and **`save as`** them again as png and try. Weird but it works. I was facing same issue and This steps did the trick.

and For **"Could not find file: /Users/jimi9991/Documents/DeveloperProjects/TennisMatch4/build/Debug-iphoneos/TennisMatch4.app/LightWoodBackground.png"**, try removing that file from the application and again add it to project.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Worked perfectly